# Why use Intents in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I still don't understand what is so special about Intents.  Why not just use a new thread or just call the function?  I think I got the whole idea about intents wrong.  A simple code showing why Intents are better or when are needed would be great!

Comment: @Amaterasu  I just want to understand why Intents are used or when they should be used.

Comment: @Amaterasu I disagree. There could be some good facts as to why one way of doing something is better than another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intents are get widely used in android to switch from one activity to other . it is good practice to use intents . Using intents we can pass/send values from one activity to another. So it can be used as value passing mechanism. Also its syntax is very simple.so why to think about threads ?

Comment: I am just more familiar with threads since coming from different lang.

Answer (score 2):

Intents are asynchronous messages which allow application components to request functionality from other Android components. Intents allow you to interact with components from the own and other applications. For example an activity can start an external activity for taking a picture.

Intents are objects of the android.content.Intent type. Your code can send them to the Android system defining the components you are targeting. For example via the startActivity() method you can define that the intent should be used to start an activity.
An intent can contain data via a Bundle. This data can be used by the receiving component.

To start an activity use the method startActivity(intent). This method is defined on the Context object which Activity extends.

The following code demonstrates how you can start another activity via an intent.

```
# Start the activity connect to the
# specified class

Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why not just use a new thread or just call the function?

No matter what `Thread` you use, there would still need to be a mechanism to direct the message which is what an `Intent` does. It is a way to send a message. Now, it needs to be called on the `UI Thread` or have an appropriate `Context` passed because it needs this to send the message. Call what function? You are. It calls a constructor of the `Intent` class.

> A simple code showing why Intents are better or when are needed would be great!

I don't have a simple code to compare to because I'm not sure what you want to see. No one is saying that it is better than something else. As to why `Intents` are used opposed to something else? I don't know...you would have to ask the developers of the Android platform. That is what they decided to use.

When they are needed is when you want to pass a message from one `Activity` to another or from one application to another. From the docs

> An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed

I said "message" but the docs say "description of an operation to be performed" (I guess can mean the same thing). You can use them to start an `Activity`, pass data between `Activities`, and more such as telling the OS what to do at boot time. Why is it better? Better than what? That is what the developers decided to use so I guess you would have to ask them but maybe they didn't think it was better rather different.

Comment: I understand that you need them to communicate between applications but why use them when you are not communicating with other applications.  What excatly do you mean by message? examples of message?

Comment: All `Intents` are sending a message. When starting an `Activity` you are putting in the constructor, "start this class". Or you send a message with an `Intent` saying, "I want to open up the camera". Then when you use it somewhere like in `startActivity` then and only then are you completing an action.

Answer (score 0):

while I don't have an example, Intents encourage coupling components loosely.
It negates the necessity of you building your own Observer design patterns and enables Inter/Intra-Application communication.